# Using reflection to get each instance of XmlElementAttribute for a single property

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reflection, allowmultiple

I'm trying to list the possible types that *Item* could contain. However I am stuck in that I can't call Item.GetType() to loop through its Attributes as this would just return the attributes of the type that it already contained.

I have tried *TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(...)* but the Attributes container only contains one instance of *XmlElementAttribute* which is the last one applied to the property (WindowTemplate in this case)

This must be trivial but I cannot find any solution to my problem online.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ChildTemplate", typeof(ChildTmpl), Order = 1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WindowTmeplate", typeof(WindowTmpl), Order = 1)]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use TypeDescriptor for this, as System.ComponentModel always collapses attributes. You must use `PropertyInfo` and `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property, attributeType)`:

```
var property = typeof (Program).GetProperty("Item");
Attribute[] attribs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(
       property, typeof (XmlElementAttribute));
```

the array will *actually* be a `XmlElementAttribute[]` if it makes it easier:

```
XmlElementAttribute[] attribs = (XmlElementAttribute[])
     Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property, typeof (XmlElementAttribute));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works a treat.